# Adding Channel Field data inside safecracker_submit_entry_start callback function

Tags: safecracker, forms

I have Channel with fields A,B,C,D,E

I have a Safecracker form that contains input elements for channel fields A,B,C

I have an extension with the callback method

```
public function foo($safecracker_object)
{
  ...
}
```

which has the hook

```
safecracker_submit_entry_start
```

Given these data, what I want to do inside the callback function is to add channel fields D and E data manually so that in the end, what is being sent are the fields A,B,C,D,E.

Is there something in the safecracker object that enables me to add those data? I have tried using

```
public function form_hidden($name, $value = '')
```

and

```
public function form_attribute($name, $value = '')
```

in safecracker object and it did not work.

Comment: The `form_hidden()` and `form_attribute()` functions are for outputting HTML form elements, not for accessing values of a posted form, just FYI.

Comment: @DerekHogue Ok, if that is so, then it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've very little experience with Safecracker but can you not simply manipulate the `$_POST` elements? The hook is called before any entry data is processed so I can't see why that wouldn't work.

```
public function safecracker_submit_entry_start()
{
    $_POST['news_body'] = 'Test';
}
```

Comment: I tried manipulating $_POST but it did not the updated the respective Channel fields.

Comment: Are you sure that your variable names matched the field names that Safecracker generates? I checked the Safecracker source and it does access `$_POST` vars shortly after calling the `safecracker_submit_entry_start` hook. To aid with debugging you could try adjusting the value of one of the fields that's already present on the form rather than injecting a new one. If that works it's likely that you have a mismatched field name.

Comment: my keys to the $_POST  array are the short names of the fields in the channels

Comment: I've just created a [dummy extension](https://gist.github.com/4451904) and updating `$_POST` vars does seem to work. I've updated my answer with the exact code that I'm using. So long as you are using simple input/textarea fields and the fields are within the fieldset assigned to the entry's channel I can't see why this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing about safecracker is that modifying channel entries will actually trigger the channel module hooks :)

One of them might be of more use?

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/api/channel_entries/

Comment: Thank you for contributing. Can you be more specific in your answer? Is there a specific hook you are suggesting be used?