# New channel form hook, unable to get submitted data

Tags: safecracker, channel-form

I have just updated EE to 2.7.1 and see that Safecracker is now changed to Channel Form.

I have an extension which runs on submission end so have had to change the hook to the new hook for channel form.

The problem is, I am unable to get the submitted information as I did before.

Here is the top of my function, with the hook changed over.

```
public function channel_form_submit_entry_end($cf)
{       
    $entry_id = $cf->entry['entry_id'];
    $member_id = $cf->entry['author_id'];
```

How do you now go about getting submitted information, as the following isnt working.

```
$cf->entry['entry_id'];
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this inside your hook:

```
print_r($cf); exit();
```

This will let you inspect the structure of the object passed by the hook, and find where `entry_id` lives.

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly new to EE, but did implement the same channel_form_submit_entry_end($channel_form_obj) hook.
But I do not believe this hook passes any data to the function, just the channel form object.
The other 2 channel form hooks do, however, appear to pass data via the $tagdata as noted in the [docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/module/channel_form/index.html).
channel_form_entry_form_tagdata_start($tagdata, $channel_form_obj), channel_form_entry_form_tagdata_end($return_tagdata, $channel_form_obj).

**Allow me add my own correction.**

I found a way to access the form entries using $_POST in [this answer](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/2201/adding-channel-field-data-inside-safecracker-submit-entry-start-callback-functio).

function channel_form_submit_entry_start($form_obj)

$data=$_POST['title'];

// do something with $data now
echo $data
//change the data
public function safecracker_submit_entry_start()

{
    $_POST['news_body'] = 'Test';
}

Answer (score 0):

I'm late but i checked the post data using.. `ee()->input->post( 'YOUR-POST-VARIABLE', TRUE );`

But I'm using EE 3.x.x